# How to set frame rate in GLFW based metal application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal, frame-rate

I am working on a metal renderer with the GLFW windowing api (the reason I use glfw is for portability). The problem is that the frame rate is capped at sixty which I do not want, after some googling I found you can modify the frame rate through an `MTKView`, though I cannot find how to get such an object.

The questions is, can I get the `MTKView` through glfw somehow, or rather, **how should I modify the frame rate in this situation?**

Some sample code:

```
...
CAMetalLayer* layer = [CAMetalLayer new];
...  
NSWindow* window = glfwGetCocoaWindow(glfwWindow);
window.contentView.layer = layer;
windwo.contentView.wantsLayer = YES;
...
```

I must say I am completely new to Metal and I am not sure if using glfw is the way to go, I do definitely want to use Glfw since I rely on it on windows with Vulkan and I found some code can be cross platform with glfw.

(edit) Rendering happens as follows:

```
    id <CAMetalDrawable> surface = ...;
    MTLRenderPassDescriptor* render_pass = ...;
    id <MTLCommandQueue> queue = ...;
    CAMetalLayer* layer = ...;
    id <MTLRenderCommandEncoder> command = ...;
    id <MTLRenderPipelineState> pipeline = ...;

    id <MTLCommandBuffer> command_buffer = [queue commandBuffer];
    render_pass.colorAttachments[0].texture = surface.texture;
    
    command = [command_buffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor: render_pass];
    [command setRenderPipelineState: pipeline];
    [command endEncoding];
    
    [command_buffer presentDrawable: surface];
    [command_buffer commit];
    
    surface = [layer nextDrawable];
```

Thank you.

Comment: How are you presenting the drawable in the application? The easiest way to pace the app would be to use `presentDrawable:afterMinimumDuration:` method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/2806849-presentdrawable

Comment: Actually, I don't think it matters how what glfw does. If you have an `MTLCommandBuffer`, you can just present after minimum duration and it should pace the app. Unless glfw internally does some additional pacing, then you will get a weird double pacing that might or might not work.

Comment: But glfw is opensource so it should be pretty easy to figure out what it does.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I tried `afterMinimumDuration` but when I set it to `0` or something really small like `0.000001`, then it keeps rendering at 60fps, however, if I set it to 1, it renders at 1fps.
I am not sure if it is Glfw's doing, on windows with Vulkan I get ridiculous frame rates with the exact same code (apart from Vulkan >< Metal). If on Mac, I comment out the metal api calls (drawing, buffers, etc.) the frame rate is nearly 1000fps.

Comment: I mean, it works as expected. The layer is probably set up with vsync by default

Comment: " if I set it to 1, it renders at 1fps." it's exactly what it's supposed to do, it presents a drawable after waiting one second, which gives you 1 fps if you can encode all the command buffers in the frame in one second.

Comment: On macOS, you can disable vsync by setting `displaySyncEnabled` on `CAMetalLayer`. On other platforms, you can't tear the screen.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, but that too does not achieve what I am looking for, the frame rate remains the exact same (60).

Comment: Well this probably needs a sample then where it reproduces, it’s impossible to say why it does it like that